# Find and locate text in a hidden Illustrator layer

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, workflow

I am working with a AI document that has over 200 layers with country names.
All the layers are hidden and locked (because each layer contains overlapping elements with the others, so it's better not to have them visible at the same time).

When I go in `Edit` > `Find and Replace` and type a country name, for example *Finland*, Illustrator behaves as if it found something (`Find next`, `Replace`, `Replace and Find` and `Replace all` become active), but I still do not know which layer the country is in. 
Nothing changes in the layers panel.

### Is there an easy and quick way to find this layer?

Comment: I believe you need to unlock and show layers if you want to "find" something on them.

Comment: Can one unlock all and relock all easily?

Comment: For *objects*.. just use the Object menu...  for *layers*, highlight layers and use the Layers Panel menu, there should be a dynamic menu item for something along the lines of `Unlock All Layers`. Note, one of these will **not** unlock the other. So, you probably have to do both if you have both objects *and* layers locked.